# border animation on load?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to know how can i make a border effect . All i've made is this fade in effect in css3 : http://jsfiddle.net/ueu64hps/ , but i still want that sliding effect. Thanks.

As in the exemple, http://velvethammer.net/ the borders are sliding in from 20% to 100%. **This is kind of what I want, but on page load.**

I will paste my code below:

The HTML:

```
<div id="left" class = "slow fade-in"></div>
  <div id="right" class = "slow fade-in"></div>
  <div id="top" class = "slow fade-in"></div>
  <div id="bottom" class = "slow fade-in"></div>


  <div class = "wrap">
    <h2>Some random text.</h2>     
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#top, #bottom, #left, #right {
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
}
#left, #right {
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 35px;
}
#left { 
  left: 0; 
}
#right { 
  right: 0; 
}
#top, #bottom {
  left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 35px;
}
#top { 
  top: 0; 
}
#bottom { 
  bottom: 0; 
}
.wrap{
  margin:35px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
  opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;
}
.fade-in.slow {
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could animate `#left, #right` together, and `#top, #bottom` together. Here's the [complete example](http://jsfiddle.net/ueu64hps/1/).

Create 2 animation sets, one for width and other for height:

```
/* For left and right animation */
@-webkit-keyframes easeInLeft { from { width:0; } to { width:30px; } }
@-moz-keyframes    easeInLeft { from { width:0; } to { width:30px; } }
@keyframes         easeInLeft { from { width:0; } to { width:30px; } }

/* For top and bottom animation */    
@-webkit-keyframes easeInTop { from { height:0; } to { height:30px; } }
@-moz-keyframes    easeInTop { from { height:0; } to { height:30px; } }
@keyframes         easeInTop { from { height:0; } to { height:30px; } }
```

And then play it on their respective `div`s:

```
.ease-in-left {
    width: 0; /* Set it to 0 initially */
    -webkit-animation: easeInLeft ease-in 1;  
       -moz-animation: easeInLeft ease-in 1;
            animation: easeInLeft ease-in 1;
}

.ease-in-top {
    height: 0; /* Set it to 0 initially */
    -webkit-animation: easeInTop ease-in 1;  
       -moz-animation: easeInTop ease-in 1;
            animation: easeInTop ease-in 1;
}
```

And here's what the `div`s look like:

```
<div id="left" class = "slow fade-in ease-in-left"></div>
<div id="right" class = "slow fade-in ease-in-left"></div>
<div id="top" class = "slow fade-in ease-in-top"></div>
<div id="bottom" class = "slow fade-in ease-in-top"></div>
```

I left the `.fade-in` class as is (you should probably rename that), with the common animation properties, and removed the `opacity` properties from wherever they were set.